# Update .json file with jquery post to php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm really new to PHP programming and I'm trying to achieve following structure with PHP to .json file;

```
{

  "1": {
    "number": "4",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "2": {
    "number": "0",
    "color": "green"
  }

}
```

What I would like to do is, when I post data to this with "add.php" file. It would update the .json file as below;

```
{

  "1": {
    "number": "4",
    "color": "black"
  },
  "2": {
    "number": "0",
    "color": "green"
  },
  "3": {
    "number": "12",
    "color": "red"
  }


}
```

The "number" and "color" would come from the post I post from the index.php with jQuery;

```
$('#add_outcome').on('submit',function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'add.php',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data : {
            "number" : $('#add_outcome select').val(),
            "color" : $('#add_outcome #color_info').val()
        },
        success: function(json) {
            console.log("Done, data sent");             }
    });
});
```

Is it possible to update this kinda structure with PHP? If it's not possible to count the next "ID" which in my examples are 1, 2, 3 etc (Increasing by submit) I can post the data from index PHP.

Most important to me right now is to get familiar how to update this sort of structure with PHP.

The JSON data would come from file, path to it is "json/outcome.json" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code into your `add.php` file

```
<?php
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('json/outcome.json'), true);

$json_array[] = array('number' => $_POST['number'], 'color' => $_POST['color']);
file_put_contents('json/outcome.json', json_encode($json_array));
?>
```

Comment: `json_decode` already returns an array of arrays, why do you wrap it in another?

Comment: That code really advanced my project!
I got it working for me by removing [] from the ;
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('json/outcome.json'), true);

Huge thanks for both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$file = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to.json'), true);
//do whatever you want as $file is now an array
$file[] = array('number' => 12, 'color' => 'red');
file_put_contents('path/to.json', json_encode($file));
```